# Take only the first that satisfies the second condition

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have a c# object with date field and foreign key. I have created one double index on these fields.

```
public class Session : DbObject
{        
    [DataMember]
    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    [Index(IsUnique = false, Order = 2)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Index(IsUnique = false, Order = 1)]
    public int PatientId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Patient Patient { get; set; }     
}
```

I need to take a list from the 'Sessions' as follow:
I have a list of patients ids and a date. 
I need to get one Session for each patient that its date is newest from all the rest.

something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Sessions WHERE PatientId IN (1, 2, ...) AND TOP(Date < SOME_DATE)
```

I know this query is nonsense. It just to clarify my intention.

***It is important to use the indexes because this table is huge.

If it is possible, I would like to know if I can write it in c# and entity framework.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***It is important to use the indexes because this table is huge.

The LINQ query would look something like:

```
var ids = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
var dt = DateTime.Now;
var q = from s in db.Sessions
        where ids.Contains(s.Id)
            && s.Date > dt
        group s by s.PatientId into byPatientId
        select byPatientId.OrderBy(s => s.Date).Take(1);
```

But that's perhaps not the most efficient query.  If that's too slow, you might want to consider a store query instead:

```
db.Sessions.FromSql(@"
with q as 
( 
   select Date, 
          PatientId, 
          row_number() over (partition by PatientId order by Date desc) rn
   where PatientId in (1,2,3,5,6,3)
     and Date > @d
   from Sessions
)
select Date, PatientId
from q
where rn = 1
", dt);
```

Comment: Would you please explain to me whats going on here? What is the running time of that? Also, how do you use the double index here? It seems that you don't really use the indexes, and when I have millions of entries that will be slow.

Comment: The second code syntax is wrong in c# and in SQL Microsoft studio 2017

Comment: Ok now I understand. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to write it in mySQL which doesn't support the 'with' statement?